# proxies должен обновлятся раз в 5 выполнений цикла

Tags: python, python-3.x

`s.proxies.update` должен выполнятся раз в пять циклов, как это можно реализовать в данном коде?

```
  password = input("Введите пароль: ")
numbers = open("sc_base.txt", "r").readlines()
proxies = open("proxy_test.txt", "r").readlines()
for proxy_list,login in zip(proxies,numbers):
    try:
        s = requests.Session()
        s.proxies.update({'http': 'http://' + proxy_list})
        print('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
        print(proxy_list)
        print(login)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: можно добавить переменную, с каждым проходом делать +1 и проверять условие при делении на 5

Comment: Я подумал так сделать, но не понял, как сделать проверку.

Comment: проверяйте на остаток от деления

Comment: @xkrystalll `Итерация % 5 == 0`, получить итерацию с помощью `enumerate` можно

Comment: я попробывал сделать вот так: `if _iter_ % 5 == 0:
   s = requests.Session()
   s.proxies.update({'http': 'http://' + proxy_list})
   _iter_ = 0  
  else:
   pass` но всё равно идёт 1к1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе, уже в комментариях написали, в `Python` такие вещи обычно делают через `enumerate` и проверку на остаток от деления `%`:

```
for i,(proxy_list,login) in enumerate(zip(proxies,numbers)):
    # ...
    if i % 5 == 0:
       # ...
```

Непонятно только, когда вы хотите, чтобы началось срабатывание. В данном случае сработает на первом же проходе, потом 4 прохода цикла будут пропущены, поскольку `enumerate` нумерует с нуля.

Если надо наоборот первые 4 прохода пропустить, а срабатывание сделать на пятом, то можно использовать параметр, задающий начало отсчёта для `enumerate`:

```
for i,(proxy_list,login) in enumerate(zip(proxies,numbers), 1):
```

Comment: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
Это исключение от строки с циклом for

Comment: @xkrystalll Поправил код