# Как пропускать исполнение цикла for

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как сделать так, что бы пока итерация не достигла 5, цикл не выполнялся, а после этого выполнился 1 раз и снова не выполнялся до тех пор, пока итерация опять не достигнет 5 в этом коде (цикл на 8 строчке, proxy-list):

```
import os
import requests
import time
i = 0
password = input("Введите пароль: ")
numbers = open("sc_base.txt", "r").readlines()
proxies = open("proxy_test.txt", "r").readlines()
for i,(proxy_list,login) in enumerate(zip(proxies,numbers), 1):
    try:
        i += 1
        if i % 5 == 0:
            s = requests.Session()
            s.proxies.update({'http': 'http://' + proxy_list})
        else:
            pass
        print('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
        print(login)
        print(proxy_list + ' + PROXY')
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1163235/398802

Comment: Нет, это другой вопрос, тут уже другая проблема, цикл выполняется, но переменная s.proxies.update обновляется раз в 5 обновлений цикла, а мне нужно что бы цикл и s.proxies.update обновлялись одновременно, раз в 5 выполнений цикла login - numbers

Comment: Не понял условия до сих пор

Comment: proxy_list должен обновлятся раз в 5 проходов цикла, а login каждый раз

Comment: Сделайте цикл только по login и обновляйте в нём proxy_list по такому же условию, как в прошлом вопросе

Comment: Но если я перезапускаю цикл, то он начинает выполнение сначала, а не продолжает.

Comment: Сразу бы так сказал "proxy_list должен обновлятся раз в 5 проходов цикла, а login каждый раз"

Comment: Я не очень силён в обьяснении, извините уж, какой есть. Стараюсь что бы было понятнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас смешались два индекса - я их разделил на `i_proxy` и `i`.
Перебор proxy убрал из цикла и индексацию сделал в ручную.

```py
import os
import requests
import time

i_proxy = 0
password = input("Введите пароль: ")
numbers = open("sc_base.txt", "r").readlines()
proxies = open("proxy_test.txt", "r").readlines()
for i,login in enumerate(numbers, 1):
    if i % 5 == 0:
        i_proxy += 1
    try:
        s = requests.Session()
        s.proxies.update({'http': 'http://' + proxies[i_proxy]})
        print('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
        print(login)
        print(proxies[i_proxy] + ' + PROXY')
```

Comment: NameError: name 'proxy_list' is not defined

Comment: да, забыл заменить на `proxies`.

Answer (score 0):

привел минимальный пример как можно решить ваш вопрос, у вас почти правильно было только вы зачем то `i` в цикле инкрементируете, когда это в enumerate само итак происходит

здесь каждые пять итераций печатается "обновляем proxy", и на каждой итерации печатается, что "обновляем login"

```
proxies = [i for i in range(10)]

for i, proxy in enumerate(proxies, 1):
    if i % 5 == 0:
        # update proxy here
        print(f'обновляем proxy')

    # update login here
    print(f'обновляем login')
```

Comment: Простите за мою безтактность, но можете, пожалуйста, дать пример в моём коде, а то я не совсем понимаю что к чему :(